# Python String Manipulation - Split, Slice, Convert from HEX to DEC

Tags: python, string, split, hex, slice

I have the following string:

```
s = "0015CB,0,0,01,006D,0016CF1,4,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00F4E7D,1,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0008184,8,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA704,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,0014EC8,2,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FAEEA,9,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FADE9,5,000D,01,0202,01,0E09,01,02,00,006D,0000,0,0,01,006D,00FA5A5,3,000D"
```

Selcuk kindly assisted in splitting this at every iteration of `000D`so the first value extracted was `0016CF1,4`

Now I need help converting the first part of this value from Hex to Dec and leaving the digit after the comma as it is. So it will be `93425,4` or `93425 4`

I have the following so far and it works, but is not really elegant, can some please help to make this more efficient/cleaner. Thanks.

```
my_list = [e[-9:] for e in s.split(",000D")]
print(my_list)

# Output = ['0016CF1,4', '00F4E7D,1', '0008184,8', '00FA704,9', '0014EC8,2', '00FAEEA,9', '00FADE9,5', '00FA5A5,3', '']


# for testing print the first value from the list [0]
# output = 0016CF1,4

print(my_list[0])

# save my_list in a string called list and remove the comma and check digit
# output = 0016CF1

list=str(my_list)
result = [e[-7:] for e in list.split(",")]
print(result[0])

# convert the first value from HEX to DEC
# output= 93425

res1 = int(result[0],16)
print(res1)

#  get the checkdigit for the first value in the list
checkdigit = [f[-1:] for f in s.split(",000D")]
print(checkdigit[0])

# output = 4

#  join res1 and checkdigit

print(res1,checkdigit[0])

# output = 93425 4
```

Ideally I would like the above in a loop please so all the value in the original list are converted like the example first value abvove. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very compact solution:

```
my_list = ['0016CF1,4', '00F4E7D,1', '0008184,8', '00FA704,9',
           '0014EC8,2', '00FAEEA,9', '00FADE9,5', '00FA5A5,3']

result = [f'{int(x[:-2], 16)} {x[-1]}' for x in my_list]
```

Here is the final content of `result`:

```
['93425 4', '1003133 1', '33156 8', '1025796 9',
 '85704 2', '1027818 9', '1027561 5', '1025445 3']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time to answer this, but can you please advise how I can use my original list called 'my_list' where the string manipulation takes place, or do I need to do something else to make this work? When I use my 'my_list' or 'list' - i get the error:results = [f'{int(x[:-2], 16)} {x[-1]}' for x in list]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''

Comment: @MB4ig that's because you have an empty element in my list, get rid of it!

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much Riccardo, much appreciated :)